# Need help in nesting array functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have these two arrays of JavaScript objects:

```
const types = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Paint',
    unit: 'L',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Resin',
    unit: 'mL',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Fiberglass',
    unit: 'yd',
  }
];

const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type_id: 1,
    name: 'Brand x paint',

    qty: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type_id: 1,
    name: 'Brand y paint',
    supplier: 'brand y',
    qty: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type_id: 2,
    name: 'Brand x resin',
    qty: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type_id: 2,
    name: 'Brand y resin',
    qty: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type_id: 2,
    name: 'Brand z resin',
    qty: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type_id: 2,
    name: 'Brand x fiberglass',
    qty: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type_id: 2,
    name: 'Brand y fiberglass',
    qty: 9,
  },
];
```

I want to create a new array with the types array with an additional property which is the sum of quantities on each respective type. I've came up with mapping the type array and inside the function, I assign a new property like totalQty which is equal to the filtered items of a type and then reduce with a sum accumulator. Something like this, which is horribly wrong somewhere around the filtering part:

```
const itemTypes  =  types.map( (type) => {
    type.total_qty = items
      .filter((items) => items.type_id === type.id)
      .reduce((sum, item) => sum += item.qty, 0)
  }     
)
```

I just kinda wanna make the above work but if there are better ways of adding a total_quantity property beside the type then I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you are just missing `, 0)` at the end of the reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `map` without a `return` in its callback, but instead *mutate* the given array. So `map` returns `undefined` values, while at the same time your `types` array has been updated (but not output).

Here is a bit more efficient method using a `Map` to avoid nested iterations. So it runs in *O(n)* instead of *O(n²)* time complexity.

It also avoids mutating the original `type` objects, but creates new objects (with the additional property) in the newly created array:

```js
const types = [ { id: 1, name: 'Paint', unit: 'L', }, { id: 2, name: 'Resin', unit: 'mL', }, { id: 3, name: 'Fiberglass', unit: 'yd', } ]; 
const items = [ { id: 1, type_id: 1, name: 'Brand x paint', qty: 5, }, { id: 2, type_id: 1, name: 'Brand y paint', supplier: 'brand y', qty: 3, }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, name: 'Brand x resin', qty: 5, }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, name: 'Brand y resin', qty: 2, }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, name: 'Brand z resin', qty: 3, }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, name: 'Brand x fiberglass', qty: 7, }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, name: 'Brand y fiberglass', qty: 9, }, ];

// Map keyed by type_id and with the extended type object as value 
// (initialised as 0)
const map = new Map(types.map( type => [type.id, {...type, total_qty: 0 }] ));
// Add the quantities from the items to the appropriate map-value
items.forEach(item => map.get(item.type_id).total_qty += item.qty);
// Extract the map values
const itemTypes = Array.from(map.values());
console.log(itemTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the initial value for the accumulator in `reduce`.

```
const itemsType  =  types.map( (type) => {
     const temp = items;
     type.total_qty = temp
         .filter( item => item.type_id === type.id)
         .reduce( (acc, item) => acc + item.qty, 0); // value missing here
  }     
)
```

Comment: I tested on Chrome console but I only get 3 `undefined` values.

Comment: what do you mean?, the results should be in `types`. The variable `itemsType` will always be undefined, since you're creating a property in each value of the array `types` called `total_qty`.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. I was expecting that the new array of objects was assigned to itemsType. But still that would suffice, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

More efficient alternative would be to create lookup object with the quantities by id :

```js
const types = [ { id: 1, unit: 'L', name: 'Paint', }, { id: 2, unit: 'mL', name: 'Resin', }, { id: 3, unit: 'yd', name: 'Fiberglass', } ]; 

const items = [ { id: 1, type_id: 1, qty: 5, name: 'Brand x paint', }, { id: 2, type_id: 1, qty: 3, name: 'Brand y paint', supplier: 'brand y', }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, qty: 5, name: 'Brand x resin', }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, qty: 2, name: 'Brand y resin', }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, qty: 3, name: 'Brand z resin', }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, qty: 7, name: 'Brand x fiberglass', }, { id: 3, type_id: 2, qty: 9, name: 'Brand y fiberglass', }, ];

const qtys = items.reduce((obj, item) => 
                   (obj[item.type_id] = (obj[item.type_id] || 0) + item.qty, obj), {})

const itemTypes = types.map(type => ({ ...type, total_qty: qtys[type.id] }))

console.log( JSON.stringify( itemTypes ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') )
console.log( qtys )
```

For information on spread syntax in object literals : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals